# Update the users where amount <=0 set credits

Tags: php, sql-update

```
$check_empty_user = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM bubble_spends where a_amount <= 0");
$count=$check_empty_user->num_rows;
$username23=$DBcon->query("SELECT a_name FROM bubble_spends where a_amount <= 0 LIMIT 1");

$count2=$username23->fetch_array;

 if (!$count==0) {

  $DBcon->query("DELETE FROM bubble_spends where a_amount <= 0");
  $DBcon->query("UPDATE users SET credits = credits+100000 WHERE username='$count2'");
        echo "user has been outspended";
    }
```

the main goal is to achieve through it, when a bubble_spend has an amount of less than 0, it should select a_name from bubble spends, and then update users set credits=credits+10 where username=$a_name

But this doesn't work, I am busy with this for 2 hours and I can not get the fix

Comment: UPDATE users SET credits = credits+100000 WHERE username='$count2'" what is credits+100000 credit in that and where you set it

Comment: "UPDATE users WHERE username=$count2 SET credits = credits+100000");  doesnt work either

Comment: dude i am asking you that you are setting credits+100000 so i want to know that what is credits in that and where you define that

Comment: Are you wanting to do this for all users who have < 0 credits? Or are you targeting one specific user?

Comment: in the phpmyadmin database. at users - > credits

Comment: all of em where a_amount is less then 0

Comment: Do you want to reset the users credits to 10?

Comment: Count2 is an array.  Use $count2["a_name"] or whatever

Comment: I need more clarification on how you are adjusting your credits.  Are you wanting to add 100000 credits to the users credits they already have or just want to reset them to 100000?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get all the users who have amount less than 0 in bubble_spends table, then performing a delete from that table and update on the other table.

To do this in simple way is to get all the names who have amount less than 0 from bubble_spends table and then using IN operator plus inner query to update them. Once updated, you are good to delete them from the other table.

```
$DBcon->query("UPDATE users SET credits = credits+100000 
WHERE username IN (SELECT a_name FROM bubble_spends where a_amount <= 0)");

$DBcon->query("DELETE FROM bubble_spends where a_amount <= 0");
```

This should do it.

Comment: yeah this one really should,  but it doesnt add that 100000 credits (which actualy is (a_amount2/100*wage))

Comment: That's weird. **credits = credits + 100000** is valid unless you have the wrong column name. Not sure why it does not work for you.